# Failed a VLQ audit, am I wrong here?

Tags: discussion, support, disputed-review-audits

I failed this audit: https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/9844141

The answer has been deleted, but it was to the effect of:

> You should use (link to library) in this situation.
>   It does (these things), which should address your issue.

It was short, and primarily link-based. I was close to recommending deletion for being link-only, but I hesitated because it did seem to genuinely attempt to answer the question, and it wasn't *just* a link - it did include some explanation.

I've read through some of the [discussion around deleting link answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer). In my opinion, I think this particular post qualifies as being "not great, but not a deletion candidate".

I erred on the side of keeping it, which obviously failed the audit. Is my thinking wrong in this case?

Comment: For <10k users, the full text of the deleted answer reads "An option is use swaggergo.com to host your swagger specification. SwaggerGo proxy the requests and add the expected headers." Something about their website makes my hair stand on end, and I can't quite pinpoint it (maybe it's their lack of API docs and no company information?).

Comment: Thanks for posting @MaximillianLaumeister.

Comment: This is basically spam; it's promoting a product instead of answering the question. The questioner was looking for help with their code, not for a product. Only Flexo will be able to say for sure why it was deleted though.

Comment: Spam, egg, Spam, Spam, bacon and Spam. @MaximillianLaumeister - You'd figure with their lead text about how its `The easiest way for share your interactive API documentation` that they'd show some documentation.

Comment: [@theB](https://www.google.ca/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB4QyCkwAGoVChMI-4e0uq_CyAIVDJmICh3ALgR7&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3Danwy2MPT5RE&usg=AFQjCNFaQXH6eqw7mAKsVdfvburEEiBeig&sig2=FDvuavyVduUxQglTaiSKVg&bvm=bv.105039540,d.cGU)?

Comment: @TinyGiant - I had to say it.

Answer (score 4):

That answer is borderline link-only, and basically spam.

If anything, it should've been downvoted at least.